# XAML browser application xbap

Tags: xaml, browser

Has anyone worked on the XAML browser(xbap) application?

How is it different from a typical ASP.NET web application and in what scenarios we can it be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XBAPP are not ASP.NET application. XBAPP become part of a web application, but actually downloaded to the client side and runs on the client OS. So it needs .NET 3.5 or higher on the client side. Also, it needs a certain level of trust on the client machine and normally accompanies a trust certificate.

Comment: What does it mean by saying "Part of web application"? Does it mean like it can be used in a web application like a kind of user control?

Comment: Here I am saying that it is part of the system/solution. Part implemented as web application and the rest as XBAPP. The XBAPP is downloaded to the client side and run on the client machine, not in the IIS of the web application. It is actually an windows application.